# Multiple access to email

Tags: imap, pop3

I have a peculiar problem to address: our institutional server are all based on Microsoft and emails are managed using the POP protocol.
Since we need some of them to be read by several people, but we can't operate on central servers, I thought to use one old, discarded workstation, as an IMAP server.
The idea is to create one email address on this 'server' for every POP email and download on the new address all the messages from the central server, so we can use with multiple access.
Do you think it can be possible?
How can I do it, and what software do I need (aside the IMAP server, of course)?

Comment: You can connect to Microsoft Exchange using IMAP - I do that all the time (using Thunderbird)

Comment: First of all thank you very much. So there is no need for Excange to be configured as an imap server? This is a really good thing, I'll try right now :-)

Comment: You probably need to enable/configure _something_ on the Exchange server. But I have no idea what that is - I just know that you _can_ use IMAP with Microsoft Exchange.